# Pandas: Read Timestamp from CSV in GMT then resample

Tags: python, csv, timezone, timestamp, pandas

I have a CSV with epoch GMT timestamp at irregular intervals paired with a value.  I tried reading it from the CSV but all the times zones are shifted to my local timezone.  How can I make it read in as-is (in GMT)?  Then I would like the resample to one minute intervals, HOWEVER, I would like to skip gaps which are larger than a user specified value.  If this is not possible, is there way to resample to one minute, but in the gaps, put in an arbitrary value like 0.0?

```
 Data:
 Time,Data
 1354979750250,0.2343
 1354979755250,2.3433
 1354979710250,1.2343

 def date_utc(s):
     return parse(s, tzinfos=tzutc)

 x = read_csv("time2.csv", date_parser=date_utc, converters={'Time': lambda x:datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)/1000.)}).set_index('Time')
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert local datetime to GMT datetime like this:

```
gmtDatetime = localdatetime - datetime.timedelta(hours=8)
```

The time zone is +08 (China).

Or using 'datetime.utcfromtimestamp':

```
classmethod datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
classmethod datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=None)
```

> Return the UTC datetime corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, with
>   tzinfo None. This may raise OverflowError, if the timestamp is out of
>   the range of values supported by the platform C gmtime() function, and
>   OSError on gmtime() failure. It’s common for this to be restricted to
>   years in 1970 through 2038. See also fromtimestamp().