# Converting timezones from pandas Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

I have the following in a dataframe:

```
> df['timestamps'].loc[0]
Timestamp('2014-09-02 20:24:00')
```

I know the **timezone** (I think it is **GMT**) it uses and would like to convert the entire column to **EST**. How can I do that in Pandas?

For reference, I found these other threads:

- [Changing a unix timestamp to a different timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706808/changing-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-different-timezone)
- [Pandas: Read Timestamp from CSV in GMT then resample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371476/pandas-read-timestamp-from-csv-in-gmt-then-resample)

but they work with `datetime` timestamps. E.g.:

```
> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df['timestamps'].loc[0], tz=None)
returns:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 2 datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=None)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just use `tz_convert` method.

Lets say you have a Timestamp object:

```
   stamp = Timestamp('1/1/2014 16:20', tz='America/Sao_Paulo')
   new_stamp = stamp.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

If you are interested in converting date ranges:

```
   range = date_range('1/1/2014', '1/1/2015', freq='S', tz='America/Sao_Paulo')
   new_range = range.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

For large time series:

```
   import numpy as np
   ts = Series(np.random.randn(len(range)), range)
   new_ts = ts.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

As stated in another answer, if your data does not have a timezone set, you'll need to `tz_localize` it:

```
   data.tz_localize('utc')
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try: 
`df['timestamps'][0].tz_convert('US/Eastern')` I get: 
`Exception: Cannot convert tz-naive Timestamp, use tz_localize or localize`

Comment: Same if I try working with the column directly:
`df['timestamps'].tz_convert('US/Eastern')`
`TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex`

Comment: @user815423426 you need to tz_localize first (as mentioned at end of my answer), you can't convert to a timezone if you don't know what timezone you started in.

Comment: Note: you can't use `tz_localize` or `tz_convert` directly on a *column*, only on an *index*

Comment: @joris -- could you explain or point to an example of the difference between a column and an index?  I think I'm having a related problem and can't change my dataframe's `df['time']` column from a timezone-aware UTC data to timezone naive UTC data, and I'm not sure of the right language to speak/find/search for.
.

Comment: Nowadays it is actually possible to it on a column as well. You can do `df['time'].dt.tz_localize(..)`

Comment: What if I am writing a generic function and don't know if the user is going to give me a tz aware or naïve object (I can make a logical assumption about the tz in the latter case). How do I introspect to find out what sort of object I am dealing with?

Comment: Example to localize and convert in 1 line `pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now()).tz_localize('US/Pacific').tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')`

Answer (score 6):

datetime's fromtimestamp is actually from a POSIX timestamp i.e. ms from 1970-1-1 GMT

```
In [11]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp?
Type:        builtin_function_or_method
String form: <built-in method fromtimestamp of type object at 0x101d90500>
Docstring:   timestamp[, tz] -> tz's local time from POSIX timestamp.

In [12]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 16, 0)

In [13]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1)
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 16, 0, 1)
```

*I think maybe is an issue as I'm in PST timezone.*

This is different from pandas Timestamp (although under the hood that is ns from 1970-1-1).

```
In [21]: pd.Timestamp(0)
Out[21]: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00')
```

To convert a Timestamp/datetime64 column use tz_convert (if the are tz naive, i.e. don't have a timezone yet, you'll need to tz_localize first):

```
In [31]: pd.Timestamp(0).tz_localize('UTC')
Out[31]: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')

In [32]: t = pd.Timestamp(0).tz_localize('UTC')

In [33]: t.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
Out[33]: Timestamp('1969-12-31 19:00:00-0500', tz='US/Eastern')
```

*See the [time-zone-handling section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-zone-handling).*

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to convert UTC times (originally from Unix time) to US/Eastern.

This runs in vectorised mode, so it is blazingly fast: runs in seconds for millions of rows.

Tested on Python 3.9.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": [Timestamp("2017-01-03 14:30:00.049"), Timestamp("2017-01-03 14:30:00.049"), Timestamp("2017-01-03 14:30:00.049")],
                   "x": [1,2,3]})
timestamp = df["timestamp"].values
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(timestamp)
timestamp = timestamp.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert("US/Eastern") # Convert UTC to US/Eastern
timestamp = timestamp.tz_localize(None)  # Strip timezone information off.
df["timestamp"] = timestamp.values
df
```

In:

```
              timestamp  x
2017-01-03 14:30:00.049  1
2017-01-03 14:30:00.049  2
2017-01-03 14:30:00.049  3
```

Out:

```
              timestamp  x
2017-01-03 09:30:00.049  1
2017-01-03 09:30:00.049  2
2017-01-03 09:30:00.049  3
```

### Bonus

If the column was originally in Unix time (milliseconds) use this to cast it into an array of datetime64[ns]:

```
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit="ms")
```