# How to determine if a timezone specific date in the past is daylight saving or not in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone

Is there a way I can check if a specific timezone is in daylight saving in a date I specified?

```
    test_dt = datetime(year=2015, month=2, day=1)
    pst = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
    test_dt = pst.localize(test_dt) 

    # should return False
    is_day_light_saving(test_dt)
```

Comment: Where is the time zone?

Comment: It should be arbitrary, but the example is 'America/Los_Angeles'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python daylight savings time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881025/python-daylight-savings-time)

Comment: I think `localtime` only returns the current time, I am not exactly sure if you specified `time` and `timezone` in datetime how would you determine the is daylight saving or not

Comment: @MorganThrapp That has nothing to do with this question

Comment: related: [Use Python to find out if a timezone currently in daylight savings time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19968515/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call [the `datetime.dst()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.dst):

```
def is_summer_time(aware_dt):
    assert aware_dt.tzinfo is not None
    assert aware_dt.tzinfo.utcoffset(aware_dt) is not None
    return bool(aware_dt.dst())
```

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

naive = datetime(2015, 2, 1)
pacific = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
aware = pacific.localize(naive, is_dst=None) 

print(is_summer_time(aware))
```

It is equivalent to:

```
bool(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles').dst(datetime(2015, 2, 1), is_dst=None))
```

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, timezone data is more easily dealt with timezone-sensitive pandas.Timestamp() than datetime. I am pretty sure the timezone-sensitivity infers daylight savings time from the date itself. It is trivial to convert datetime to pandas.timestamp() by first converting it to a numpy.datetime64.

```
Timestamp(numpy.datetime64('2012-05-01T01:00:00.000000'))
```

http://wesmckinney.com/blog/easy-high-performance-time-zone-handling-in-pandas-0-8-0/

[python pandas TimeStamps to local time string with daylight saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352705/python-pandas-timestamps-to-local-time-string-with-daylight-saving)

[Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64)

Also you can try looking at the pandas source code and figuring out how it deduced the tz information.
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime.c