# Is there a way to infer in Python if a date is the actual day in which the DST (Daylight Saving Time) change is made?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I would like to infer in Python if a date is the actual day of the year in which the hour is changed due to DST (Daylight Saving Time).

With the library `pytz` you can localize a datetime and the actual DST change is correctly done. Furthermore, there is the method `dst()` of the library `datetime` that allows you to infer if an actual date is in summer or winter time ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146092/how-to-determine-if-a-timezone-specific-date-in-the-past-is-daylight-saving-or-n)). However, I would like to infer the actual day in which a DST change is made.

Concretely, I would need a function (for example `is_dst_change(date, timezone)`) that receives a date and returns True only for those days of the year that do have an hour change. For example:

```py
import pytz
import datetime

def is_dst_change(day, timezone):
    # Localize
    loc_day = pytz.timezone(timezone).localize(day)

    # Pseudocode: Infer if a date is the actual day in which the dst hour change is made
    if loc_day is dst_change_day:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# In the timezone 'Europe/Madrid', the days in which the DST change is made in 2021 are 28/03/2021 and 31/10/2021
is_dst_change(day=datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=3, day=28), timezone = 'Europe/Madrid')  # This should return True
is_dst_change(day=datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=10, day=31), timezone = 'Europe/Madrid')  # This should return True
is_dst_change(day=datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=2, day=1), timezone = 'Europe/Madrid')  # This should return False
is_dst_change(day=datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=7, day=1), timezone = 'Europe/Madrid')  # This should return False
```

Thus, in the above example the only days of 2021 for which the function `is_dst_change(day, timezone='Europe/Madrid')` will return `True` are 28/03/2021 and 31/10/2021. For the rest of the days of the year 2021, it must return `False`. Is there a way to infer this with Python?

Comment: Arizona and New Mexico are in the same timezone, but Arizona doesn't change to Daylight Savings Time.

Comment: @Barmar I think this is mitigated by using the `[Country]/[City]` timezone identifiers, no? As opposed to using the more broad timezone-only identifiers like `EST`/`EDT`, `PST`/`PDT`?

Comment: @esqew That's correct, I hadn't thought of that case.

Comment: @Barmar you'll have to use [IANA time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) here

Comment: @esqew abbreviations like EST/EDT, PST/PDT are not *time zones* in a geographical sense, they just tell you UTC offsets of certain time zones during a certain part of the year. And many of them are ambiguous, just search for BST for example.

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for pointing that out; I had a hunch there was some detail about those I was missing in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [datetime.dst()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.dst) (a change in UTC offset is not necessarily a DST transition):

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9+

def is_date_of_DSTtransition(dt: datetime, zone: str) -> bool:
    """
    check if the date part of a datetime object falls on the date
    of a DST transition.
    """
    _d = datetime.combine(dt.date(), time.min).replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo(zone))
    return _d.dst() != (_d+timedelta(1)).dst()
```

e.g. for tz [Europe/Berlin](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/@2950159):

```
for d in range(366):
    if is_date_of_DSTtransition(datetime(2021, 1, 1) + timedelta(d), "Europe/Berlin"):
        print((datetime(2021, 1, 1) + timedelta(d)).date())
# 2021-03-28
# 2021-10-31
```

---

Note: I'm using [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) here instead of `pytz`; for legacy code, there is a [pytz deprecation shim](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/). Here's a `pytz` version anyway (needs an additional `normalize`):

```
import pytz
def is_date_of_DSTtransition(dt: datetime, zone: str) -> bool:
    _d = pytz.timezone(zone).localize(datetime.combine(dt.date(), time.min))
    return _d.dst() != pytz.timezone(zone).normalize(_d+timedelta(1)).dst()
```

Answer (score 2):

If today's UTC offset is different than tomorrow's, then today is a DST change.

```
def is_dst_change(day: datetime.datetime, timezone):
    # Override time to midnight
    day = day.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    tz = pytz.timezone(timezone)
    return(tz.utcoffset(day+datetime.timedelta(days=1)) != 
            tz.utcoffset(day))
```

"Today" is defined in this code as midnight to midnight.

Comment: Beat me to it! [Repl.it demo](https://replit.com/@esqew/AwkwardBitesizedRevisioncontrol#main.py) I think this is likely the most balanced way to determine this, barring an ultra-optimized `is_dst_change`-esque function being provided by `pytz` OOTB.

Comment: If `day` is a datetime object and the hour attribute is *after* the DST change, I think this won't give a correct result. You might want to normalize to the date.