# Converting multiple UTC timestamps columns to US/Pacific in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dataset containing 2 timestamp columns with string format `YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`. The timezone of these timestamps is not included in the string, but they are in UTC and I want to convert them to US/Pacific.

My dataset is in a csv file, so I'm parsing those 2 timestamp columns using

`df = pd.read_csv("my_dataset.csv", parse_dates=['timestamp_col1', 'timestamp_col2'])`

After reading some posts here it seems the below (example for one column only) could be a possible solution

`pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp_col1, utc=True).astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific'))`

However, I'm getting the error below. Any insights into how to fix this or is there a better way to do this?

`'Series' object has no attribute 'astimezone'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [`dt.tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp_col, utc=True)
#0   2022-10-10 10:10:00+00:00
#Name: timestamp_col, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp_col, utc=True).dt.tz_convert(tz="US/Pacific")
#0   2022-10-10 03:10:00-07:00
#Name: timestamp_col, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Pacific]
```

---

Data:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""timestamp_col
2022-10-10 10:10:00
"""), parse_dates=['timestamp_col'])

df
        timestamp_col
0 2022-10-10 10:10:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pandas.Timestamp` object has its native timezone feature. Localize it with the `tz` argument and convert it simply with the [`tz_convert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.tz_convert.html) method. So no need to mingle packages

```py
pd.Timestamp.now(tz='UTC').tz_convert('US/Pacific')
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653529/converting-timezones-from-pandas-timestamps#25654328) covered it also.

You can also convert all timestamps of a series by using `apply`

```py
sr = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp.now(tz='UTC'), pd.Timestamp.now(tz='UTC')])
sr.apply(lambda x: x.tz_convert('US/Pacific'))
```

One needs to use this workaround since `pandas.Series.tz_conver()` expects a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` so that it converts the index and not the values.